# How to add an attribute to XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am returning an object from a web service.  It arrives in XML format -

```
<DailyTracker xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MSI.Web.MSINet.BusinessEntities">
  <ClientId>2147483647</ClientId>
  <ClientRosterId>2147483647</ClientRosterId>
  <Dept>
    <DepartmentID>2147483647</DepartmentID>
    <DepartmentName>String content</DepartmentName>
    <EmailAddress>String content</EmailAddress>
    <Location>2147483647</Location>
    <PayCode>String content</PayCode>
  </Dept>
etc, etc...
</DailyTracker>
```

This is coming from an asp.net website using c#.  I am returning an object of type DailyTracker. 
how can I add an attribute to one of the elements?  Is that possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instantiate an `XDocument` using the XML returned from the service. Get the `XElement` that you want, then add a new `XAttribute` to it:

```
XDocument document = new XDocument(xmlString);
XElement element = document.Element("myElement");
element.Add(new XAttribute("MyAttr", "My Value"));
```

Comment: Thanks for responding Dave.  Originally, I had tried building an xml document, but got an error from the server saying the document couldn't be serialized.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the Serialization process and add custom attributes to the Serialized XML content similar to the one that is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/athddy89%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I looked at the link but couldn't see how to apply it to what I need.  I simply have a REST web service that needs to return an XML doc.  A return type of XMLDocument upsets the system.  So - what I am doing now is returning an XElement, which seems to give me everything I want except xml header info.  Maybe I can live without that.